# black screen simple kivy with colab

Tags: python, linux, kivy, google-colaboratory

I have made a simple app with kivy, just to test how to create a .apk and using colab to compile I get a black screen on my phone and in BlueStacks.
This is the app:

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class BoxLayoutMain(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass

class dctApp(App):
    pass

dctApp().run()
```

and dctApp.kv:

```
BoxLayoutMain:

<MainWidget>:

<BoxLayoutMain>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    Label:
        text: "Lash"
        font_name: "fonts/DINNeuzeitGrotesk-Light Regular.ttf"
        font_size: "40dp"
        size_hint: 1, 0.1
        background_color: (255/255, 142/255, 142/255, 1)
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: self.background_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos


    Carousel:
        direction: "bottom"

        Button:
            text: "this is a test"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint: 1, 0.1

        Button:
            text: "B"
            background_normal: ""
            background_color: (255/255, 142/255, 142/255, 255/255)

        Button:
            text: "B"
            background_normal: ""
            background_color: (255/255, 142/255, 142/255, 255/255)

        Button:
            text: "B"
            background_normal: ""
            background_color: (255/255, 142/255, 142/255, 255/255)
```

It's basically a .py file and a .kv file to show some items. When I run it in Pycharm it works fine, but when I create the .apk in Colab, it's just black.
Please help! I have no idea what to do!
Thank you

Comment: Most of the question is lack of clarity but your question has more then enough clarity. If something is unnecessary then delete that. It is looking mess. Read this [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and edit your question formatting as well.

Comment: Ok so I've edited and simplified the question, hope this helps!! thanks!

Comment: Ok so I've deleted the .kv file and done everything in the main.py and now it works... am I doing something wrong when referencing the .kv file?

Comment: Yeah! It is much cleaner now, you may get help, but question will be in trend when asked, mostly but now you will get help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `kv` file name is wrong. It should be `dct.kv`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv).

Comment: I changed it to dctapp.kv (from dctApp.kv) and it worked!